# For loop not starting at 2, and consequently missing out the second field

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, laravel-5, iteration

I have a large form, which when submitted to the database, it needs splitting into odd and even (based on their HTML name), so I can perform a calculation on them.

There are 120 total `HTML Input` fields, so 60 odd and 60 even.

The `for loops` that iterates through them are:

```
  $h=0; $o=0;

    for($i=1; $i<=119; $i+=2)
    {
      $h = $h + Input::get($i);
    }

    for($i=2; $i<=120; $i+=2)
    {
      $o = $o + Input::get($i);
    }
```

What I am finding is that the odd number for loop is working correctly, but even though the second loop begins at 2, it is skipping adding that `Input::get($i);` and moving onto the 4th input.

If I echo the `odd` for loop, it outputs (with all the input values at 1):

```
for($i=2; $i<=120; $i+=2)
{
  echo $i;
  echo (",");
  $o = $o + Input::get($i);
  echo (Input::get($i));
}
```

> 2,14,16,18,110,112,114,116,118,

So as you can see, it isn't picking up the '1' value from the 2nd input field.

Any help as to why this is would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PHP arrays start at `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need two loops to accomplish this, use the modulo math function to determine if there is a remainder of 0 when dividing by 2 (indicating an even number), try this out:

```
 for($i=0; $i<=120; $i++)
 {
   if($i%2 == 0) //even
      $o = $o + Input::get($i);
   else //odd
      $h = $h + Input::get($i);
 }
```

Comment: Now that you are testing for odd/even you must increment $i by one, not two ($i++) and start at zero.

Comment: Whether this is better style is debatable. The important part of the solution is starting at `0` instead of `2`. The loop test should probably be `<120` rather than `<= 120`

Answer (score 0):

You should make a single loop that iterates from 1 to 120.  Then test if the counter is odd/even using the modulus operator ($a % $b).

i.e. if $a % 2 = 0 then the value is even else it is odd.

Comment: Agree,  except the loop should start at 0.